# WordPress: change a tag's url and order by date in ascending manner

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks

I have the following tag in my WordPress site:

```
http://www.example.com/tag/collection-100
```

and I want to change the tag's url to http://www.example.com/legends as well as make the posts displayed on that page to be ordered by date in ascending manner at the moment they are displayed in a descending way.

I've searched for plugin which can do this but I couldn't find anything on WordPress' site.

I've also tried creating a new template and using the following code in it:

```
query_posts( 'tag=collection-100&order=ASC' );
```

which fetches the first 18 posts but the pagination doesn't work properly and instead it always shows the first 18 posts.

Any help much appreciated : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom template like this "example-template.php" and write your query like this:

```
get_header();

$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'your-post-type',  'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => ASC ) ); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    //print your needs
endwhile;

get_footer();
```

Comment: This seems to work but now I don't have pagination : (

Comment: I've updated my question, do you think there is way to fix the pagination when using: query_posts( 'tag=collection-100&order=ASC' ); ?

Comment: use this: `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'your-post-type',
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'orderby'=> 'date'
'paged'=>$paged
) ); `

Comment: for view pagination:  <div class="navigation">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>

Comment: I did something similar but I used wp_pagenavi